# Flags placement on x-Axis on dual pane chart

Tags: highcharts

I refer to the JSFiddle     http://jsfiddle.net/Ln3hLmgn/ and the code below. Does anyone have any idea why the flags for x-axis did not appear? It seems that this problem only occur if there is dual pane, and there are no series for the top pane.

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                },
                top: '72%',
                height: '28%',
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data,
                id: 'dataseries',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 4
                }
            }, {
                type: 'flags',
                name: 'Flags on series',
                data: [{
                    x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 22),
                    title: 'On series'
                }, {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                    title: 'On series'
                }],
                onSeries: 'dataseries',
                shape: 'squarepin'
            }, {
                type: 'flags',
                name: 'Flags on axis',
                data: [{
                    x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
                    title: 'On axis'
                }, {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 1),
                    title: 'On axis'
                }],
                shape: 'squarepin'
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable top parameter it works. Looks like a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3517)

Answer (score 0):

Remove top and height of y-Axis inside container and it places flags on the x-Axis

```
   yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            },
   },
```

Check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln3hLmgn/4/)

Comment: No. I need the flags placement to be on xAxis NOT on the series.